How to get the value of a field of a case class by reflection in Scala 3
I'm migrating code that used to use Scala 2 reflection.
I'm trying to use scala-reflection library.
I need to get the value of a field of a given name of a case class.
Example:
$ scala-cli -j system -S 3.4.2 --dep co.blocke::scala-reflection:2.0.8
scala> import co.blocke.scala_reflection.RType

scala> case class A(a: Int, b: String)
// defined case class A

scala> import co.blocke.scala_reflection.rtypes.ScalaClassRType

scala> val t = RType.of[A].asInstanceOf[ScalaClassRType[A]]
val t: co.blocke.scala_reflection.rtypes.ScalaClassRType[A] = ScalaClassRType(rs$line$2$A,rs$line$2$.A,List(),List(),List(),List(ScalaFieldInfo(0,a,IntRType(),Map(),None,None,false), ScalaFieldInfo(1,b,StringRType(),Map(),None,None,false)),Map(),List(java.lang.Object, scala.Product, java.io.Serializable),false,false,true,false,Map(),List(),List(),false)

scala> t.fields.find(_.name == "a")
val res2: Option[co.blocke.scala_reflection.rtypes.FieldInfo] = Some(ScalaFieldInfo(0,a,IntRType(),Map(),None,None,false))

scala> val c = A(3,"hola")
val c: A = A(3,hola)

In this example, how can I get the value of field a by reflection on instance c.
If it is easier, I could consider using other libraries like izumi-reflect.

You don't need reflection libs to get values of case class fields. In your example, you just need to call c.a to see the value of the field a in the instance c.

If you need a fully featured Refection API that let's you get values for instance fields and call instance methods, the Java Reflection API (package java.reflect) works with Scala classes. You might need some trial and error because if you use the Java Reflection API, you will be working with the .class file generated by the Scala compiler and it may not always match exactly what the Scala code appears to suggest.

@PJFanning, for generic programmig I do need reflection.

Runtime reflection or compile time reflection? While compile-time reflection cannot be used in every case, it is the better choice for most situations when both can be used.

Compile time reflection should be enough for my use case: generic serialization to JDBC.

So basically, something like Mirrors would be enough?

Thanks @MateuszKubuszok. I've just discovered mirrors, but don't know yet exactly how to use them.  They look like promising.

Assuming you want to serialize things by putting them into JDBC one field after another:
trait SerializationTarget
object SerializationTarget {
  val example: SerializationTarget = new SerializationTarget {}
}

this is a stub I will use as something you'd be passing around to call some API.
trait SerializeForJDBC[A] {

  def serialize(value: A, target: SerializationTarget): Unit
}

This will be the type class which would take the value of A and somehow put all its data into SerializationTarget - however that's going to look like.
We'll start with some (stub) instances showing how primitives could be handled:
object SerializeForJDBC {

  given SerializeForJDBC[Int] with
    def serialize(value: Int, target: SerializationTarget): Unit = ()
  given SerializeForJDBC[Double] with
    def serialize(value: Double, target: SerializationTarget): Unit = ()
  given SerializeForJDBC[String] with
    def serialize(value: String, target: SerializationTarget): Unit = ()
}

extension [A](value: A)
  final def serializeForJDBC(target: SerializationTarget)(using
      SerializeForJDBC[A]
  ): Unit =
    summon[SerializeForJDBC[A]].serialize(value, target)

Now, when we would call
10.serializeForJDBC(SerializationTarget.example)
20.0.serializeForJDBC(SerializationTarget.example)
"test".serializeForJDBC(SerializationTarget.example)

code would pick up the right given and use it, basically like a strategy pattern, but the strategy is DI-ed based on a type.
Finally, we would use Mirrors to generate such strategy for every case class:
object SerializeForJDBC {
  // other givens ...

  import scala.compiletime.*
  import scala.deriving.*

  inline given derived[A <: Product](using
      p: Mirror.ProductOf[A]
  ): SerializeForJDBC[A] = {
    new SerializeForJDBC[A] {
      // - p.MirroredElemTypes is a path-dependent type, which is a tuple
      //   containing types for the fields of a case class in order in which
      //   they were defined
      // - Tuple.Map turns it into (SerializeForJDBC[Field1], SerializeForJDBC[Field2], ...)
      // - summonAll takes the type of a tuple and returns a tuple of givens
      // - that's why we had to define givens before and put them into scope
      //   e.g. by putting them into the companion object of a type class
      private val instances =
        summonAll[Tuple.Map[p.MirroredElemTypes, SerializeForJDBC]].toList
          .asInstanceOf[List[SerializeForJDBC[Any]]]

      def serialize(value: A, target: SerializationTarget): Unit =
        // the easiest way of passing values into mirrors is to cast everything
        // as Any and TypeClass[Any] and make sure that indices are correct
        // e.g. using .zip
        value.productIterator.zip(instances).foreach { case (field, instance) =>
          instance.asInstanceOf[SerializeForJDBC[Any]].serialize(field, target)
        }
    }
  }
}

Finally, we can call it:
case class Example(a: Int, b: Double, c: String)

Example(1, 2.0, "3").serializeForJDBC(SerializationTarget.example)

It would create a new instance of SerializeForJDBC[Example] every time it is needed. It shouldn't be much of an issue, but if we want to cache the instance, we can make use of derives keyword (since we defined the mirror-based method as derived):
case class Example(a: Int, b: Double, c: String) derives SerializeForJDBC

Example(1, 2.0, "3").serializeForJDBC(SerializationTarget.example)

In your actual code you'd have to replace SerializationTarget with however you interact with JDBC, replace the bodies of primitive givens and adjust how you'd combine instances for each field into an instance of a whole case class.
An alternative to build-in Mirrors is Magnolia library - since it's macro-based it's able to provide slightly better error messages than missing implicits/givens. It's also a good choice if one want to have a cross-compiled solution between Scala 2 and Scala 3.

I've followed your example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78838164/scala-3-compile-time-mirrors-how-to-get-field-names-when-i-dont-have-an-instan, but there is still a thing I don't know how to implement.
